# Powershell get values and create table

Tags: xml, powershell

I´ve this xml file to get some filtered data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT>
    <TIME_ORDER>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts1" TIME_VALUE="3060"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts2" TIME_VALUE="81090"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts3" TIME_VALUE="81114"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts4" TIME_VALUE="104639"/>
    </TIME_ORDER>
    <ANNOTATION>
        <ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION ANNOTATION_ID="a1" TIME_SLOT_REF1="ts1" TIME_SLOT_REF2="ts2">
            <ANNOTATION_VALUE>los juegos</ANNOTATION_VALUE>
        </ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION>
    </ANNOTATION>
    <ANNOTATION>
        <ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION ANNOTATION_ID="a2" TIME_SLOT_REF1="ts3" TIME_SLOT_REF2="ts4">
            <ANNOTATION_VALUE>el arte</ANNOTATION_VALUE>
        </ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION>
    </ANNOTATION>
</ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT>
```

I need to get  TIME_VALUE , where the  TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID is equal TIME_SLOT_REF1 and   TIME_SLOT_REF2 on the TIME_ORDER by ANNOTATION_VALUE

This is a video time duration by topic

Example:

```
    ANNOTATION_VALUE "los juegos" is the video topic
    TIME_SLOT_REF1="ts1" is the video start time
    TIME_SLOT_REF2="ts2" is the video end time
```

I need to get the the time in  TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts1" TIME_VALUE="3060" and TIME_SLOT    TIME_SLOT_ID="ts2" TIME_VALUE="81090"

In the end i need a table that contains:

```
Start_Time     End_Time       Topic

3060           81090           los juegos
```

How can i resolve this issue?

I`m tring to use this code:

```
    Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Input *.eaf | ForEach-Object {

    [xml] $xml =Get-Content $_.FullName

   foreach($Annotation in $xml.ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT.TIER.ANNOTATION) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
    Start = $xml.ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT.TIME_ORDER.TIME_SLOT.TIME_SLOT_ID =     ($_.ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION.TIME_SLOT_REF1).TIME_VALUE
    End   = $xml.ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT.TIME_ORDER.TIME_SLOT.TIME_SLOT_ID = ($_.ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION.TIME_SLOT_REF2).TIME_VALUE
    Title = $_.ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION.ANNOTATION_VALUE
   }}}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The XML sample is invalid (there's a `</HEADER>` closing tag, but no corresponding `<HEADER>` tag)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, you right, my bad.

Comment: You want the output table to contain start/end for _all the movies_, or just a _specific movie_ (by title/ANNOTATION_VALUE)?

Comment: All the movies, like random values, this is just a piece of original xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all the `ANNOTATION` nodes, then use the TS references to query the appropriate value in the `TIME_ORDER` node:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT>
    <TIME_ORDER>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts1" TIME_VALUE="3060"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts2" TIME_VALUE="81090"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts3" TIME_VALUE="81114"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts4" TIME_VALUE="104639"/>
    </TIME_ORDER>
    <ANNOTATION>
        <ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION ANNOTATION_ID="a1" TIME_SLOT_REF1="ts1" TIME_SLOT_REF2="ts2">
            <ANNOTATION_VALUE>los juegos</ANNOTATION_VALUE>
        </ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION>
    </ANNOTATION>
    <ANNOTATION>
        <ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION ANNOTATION_ID="a2" TIME_SLOT_REF1="ts3" TIME_SLOT_REF2="ts4">
            <ANNOTATION_VALUE>el arte</ANNOTATION_VALUE>
        </ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION>
    </ANNOTATION>
</ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT>
'@

foreach($Annotation in $xml.SelectNodes('/ANNOTATION_DOCUMENT/ANNOTATION')) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Start = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//TIME_ORDER/TIME_SLOT[@TIME_SLOT_ID = '$($Annotation.ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION.TIME_SLOT_REF1)']").TIME_VALUE
        End   = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//TIME_ORDER/TIME_SLOT[@TIME_SLOT_ID = '$($Annotation.ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION.TIME_SLOT_REF2)']").TIME_VALUE
        Title = $Annotation.ALIGNABLE_ANNOTATION.ANNOTATION_VALUE
    }
}
```

Which, with your sample data, produces a table like:

```
Start End    Title
----- ---    -----
3060  81090  los juegos
81114 104639 el arte
```

Comment: thanks again. But using Xpath i don´t get any reults, @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: I`ve edit my answer with your code adapted

Comment: @Paulo Updated, please try again - I forgot to change `$_` to `$Annotation` before